# How to recode multiple text variables in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need advice on how I should recode text to numbers or vice versa or a combination of text and numbers. In the example, I need to recode Singapore to 1, Malaysia to 2, Japan to 3 and Vietnam to 4 and so on. Column A contains all the countries, and column B should contain the recode data. I tried using the replace and substitute commands and while it is able to do the job, it only replaces one text within a single cell.  Because of this, I am not able to copy the formula down the column.  Is there a single formula that I can include all the variables I want to recode, then apply the formula to all affected data column-wise?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S58EH.jpg)

Comment: You could use vlookup to assign he number and then copy/paste as values to remove the formulas. Alternatively you could use find and replace by pressing ctrl + H

Answer (score 0):

A lookup table would be conventional but:

```
=MATCH(A2,{"Singapore","Malaysia","Japan","Vietnam"},0)
```

in B2 and copied down might serve (extended with more countries to suit).